# How to Update highchart dynamically from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

I have an highchart in my html page. I don't use any backend coding. So far, I have managed to get the data for the chart form html  tag using javascript.

Now I want to change the content of pre tag from an external file (csv, excel or anything) using ajax. I know I cannot do that since I do not have a server. I tried uploading the file on dropbox and accessing it. But I can't get it to work.

Is there any solution for this? Please help me to change the content of the pre tags in html.

Comment: please show some code to help understand your solution better. preferably in a codepen/jsfiddle

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.knowstack.com/different-ways-of-loading-highcharts-data/

Comment: Take a look on it :- http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/dynamic-chart-wont-pull-data-t31301/